# Can I upload a file to GCS from Google Endpoints?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to upload a file from API Rest (Google Endpoints) to GCS, but I have retrieve a lot of errors. I don't know if I'm using a bad way or simply Google Endpoints does not upload a file.

I'm trying who my customers upload files to my project bucket.

I read "**Endpoints doesn't accept the multipart/form-data encoding so you can't upload the image directly to Endpoints**".

Mike answered me [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26948999/upload-image-to-appengine-datastore-using-blobstore-and-endpoints) but dont know how to implement that on my project.

I'm using this libray (Python): 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/

If is possible, whats the better way? Any example?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

I think what Mike means in the previous post, is that you should use Blobstore API to upload file to GCS, instead of using endpoints, and take the data again to the blobstore.

But that will depends on what platform is your client. If you use Web-based client, you should use ordinary way just as Mike has explained (by using HTML form and handler). But if you use Android or mobile client, you can use GCS Client library or GCS REST API.

Comment: Yosi, do you know how storage.object.insert works? It' from Cloud Storage API. I need to do the same.

Comment: Try not to send the file to Endpoints. Instead use blobstore API. Blobstore API will work like this: You send the file to the Blobstore services, and you should make a handler, and upload that to GCS. It's that simple. You don't have to make it complicated by sending it to endpoint. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore

Comment: Yes, I did that. My Endpoints /getUploadURL generate a blobstore URL. So, in the form I point the action="" to this generated URL. Since uploaded, how can I get the url and return it ?

Comment: Yosi, thanks. Works perfectly. Now, you know how can I get the current user? I'm using users.get_current_user() but returns None. Any idea?